# How to optimize worker_processes and worker_connections in nginx?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, aws-opsworks

I would like to optimize the nginx configuration in an EC2 instance. The goal is to serve as many as possible concurrent user requests in a rails / unicorn app(s)

**Instance Specs**

```
vCPU(s):  2 
ECU:      6.5 
MEMORY:   17.1 GB
```

**Currently configurtation:**

```
worker_processes = 4
worker_connections = 12288
```

**Monitoring tools report:**

```
Memory usage: Around 80%
CPU usage: Around 20%
```

Is it possible to achieve better performance in nginx with the current CPU and memory available?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general rule of thumb I tend to follow for an nginx + unicorn setup is as follows:

1. Nginx worker processes = number of cores
2. Nginx worker connections = A really high number (10000+). This depends on your keep alive time, but it makes sense to have a lot of connections available should you need it.
3. Unicorn worker processes: Minimum is the number of cores. I tend to increase this if the processes are relatively lightweight (leaving plenty of available RAM).

It's a little hard to understand how many cores you actually have access to on an EC2 instance, so it's a little more trial and error based tuning when it comes to that.

Comment: Thanks, I have to go with the trial and error solution. Regards